# In TypeScript, is `this` available in the variable which initialized by function expression and arrow expression?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

In ng-bootstrap, I cannot assign the `function` to the property [ngbTypeahead]. In the sample code of [Typeahead](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#http), the arrow expression (lambda expression) is used to construct the delegate `search`.

```js
[...]
search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
text$.pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    tap(() => this.searching = true),
    switchMap(term =>
    this._service.search(term).pipe(
        tap(() => this.searchFailed = false),
        catchError(() => {
        this.searchFailed = true;
        return of([]);
        }))
    ),
    tap(() => this.searching = false)
);
[...]
```

When I changed the way to initialize the search, I got the error of `undefined` value of `this`. Here is the code of my experimentals.

```js
// this code is working fine.
[...]
costCenterFromSearch = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    return text$.pipe(
        debounceTime(300),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(term => {
        return this.http.get(this.typeAheadUrl, {
            params: new HttpParams().set("search", term)
        }).pipe(
            map(response => {
            return _.map(response, f => (<any>f).Key);
            }))
        }
        )
    );
};
[...]
```

[image: Picture1]

```js
// this code is raising errors.
[...]
costCenterFromSearch = function (text$: Observable<string>) {
    return text$.pipe(
        debounceTime(300),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        switchMap(term => {
        return this.http.get(this.typeAheadUrl, {
            params: new HttpParams().set("search", term)
        }).pipe(
            map(response => {
            return _.map(response, f => (<any>f).Key);
            }))
        }
        )
    );
};
[...]
```

[image: Picture2]

However, when I put this sample code to the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

[image: Picture3]

```js
class foo {
    a: string = "testing";
    constructor() {}

    bar_func = function () {
        console.log(this.a);
    }

    bar_lambda = () => {
        console.log(this.a);
    }
}
```

[image: Picture4]
From the Playground result, `this` are available in both function expression and arrow expression. So, I am confusing whether `this` is available in arrow expression because it does not work in ngbTypeahead property.

Comment: where are you using `costCenterFromSearch`? You will have to bind context as well.

Comment: are you injectect httpClient in your constructor?

Comment: I was just going to point out that the two are exactly the same .. I put them in a diff tool thinking I missed something .. Guessing one has a function and the other `=>`

Comment: @Pranithan T. You just discovered how arrow functions [deal with this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this)

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal, Please see [Typeahead](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples#http). I assigned `costCenterFromSearch` to `[ngbTypeahead]` in component.html.

Comment: @barbsan Thanks for your suggestion. But, Typescript engine transpiles the `=>` to be `function`. So, should we have to refer to Typescript document rather than Javascript (MDN) document

Comment: @Eliseo, Yes I am :-)

Comment: @PranithanT. Ok, here's typescript [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this). I suspect that result of transpiled `=>` depends on compiler's option `--target` (short `-t`). If it's set to `ES5` or default `ES3` then it must be transpiled to `function` but with bound context